# Describe vim replacements

Tags: vim

In almost every copy of vim that I have used, the program will give a description of changes after replacing text. (For example, something like "92 substitutions on 20 lines" would be displayed.)

I'm now working with a copy of vim that does not do that by default.

Is there a simple command (or addition I can make to my vimrc file) that will enable this behavior?

Comment: "a copy of vim" What copy?

Comment: Good question. The `vim --version` command tells me that it's version 7.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's governed by option [report](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27report%27).

You can see you current setting with

```
set report?
```

To report even the minimal change

```
set report=0
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you experience the effects of the `'report'` option. If the (substitution, or any other command's) changes cover more than those (default 2), you'll see the message, else nothing.

So, you can put the following into your `~/.vimrc` to always see those messages:

```
set report=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Although not exactly your question,
in vim's substitutions, you can use the "n" flag to count the number of
matches and lines (without real substitutions).

Example

```
:%s/a//gn
55311 matches on 17459 lines
```